# Spring Boot QueryParam Issue

Tags: java, spring, rest, model, endpoint

I have to retrieve data from query string - my url is

```
localhost:8080/api/data?query=name:Aman,Sam;surname:mishra&limit=10&index=0
```

I have to retrieve the value of url to the model not have to use `@RequestParam` as `query=name:Aman,sam;surname:mishra`.

It should be mapped to model.

My controller should be like

```
@GetMapping("/send")
public String  getData(Filters filter) {
    System.out.println(filter.getName());
    System.out.println(filter.getSurname());
    System.out.println(filter.getLimit());
    System.out.println(filter.getIndex());
    return "working";
}
```

My model should not know the structure of my Url is there any way to customize the mapping of the URL or EndPoints to model?

Comment: Use ```@RequestBody``` instead

Comment: It would be better if you provide what you have tried to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `class` to hold the attributes and pass that `class`'s object to your `controller` as shown below

> Your attribute holder class

```
class Filter {
    String name;
    String surname;
    int limit;
    int index;

    public Filter() {
    }

    public Filter(String name, String surname, int limit, int index) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.limit = limit;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

> Your End point

```
@GetMapping("/send")
public String  getData(@RequestBody Filter filter){
    System.out.println(filter.getName());
    System.out.println(filter.getSurname());
    System.out.println(filter.getLimit());
    System.out.println(filter.getIndex());
    return "working";
}
```

**Ideally you should prefer `POST` over `GET` if sending any payload **

Comment: @RequestBody with @GetMapping???
Do you know a context in which it would works?

Comment: @Izerlotti Consider a situation where you need to pass payload; not to create a resource but to retrieve some data based on that payload. Filter as shown in above case is doing the same. But as I said, having `@RequestBody` in `@GetMapping` makes confusion as our assumption in general is we pass payload in request body to create/modify a resource